# Parsing json without index name in golang

Tags: json, go

I have a json in the following format

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "status_message": "OK",
    "response": {
        "Messages": [
            "CODE_NOT_AVAILABLE"
        ],
        "UnknownDevices": {
            "": [
                "6",
                "7",
                "8",
                "9",
                "10"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As we see we are missing one index key, after unknownDevices, i am trying to unmarshal this json using golan in the following way

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type pushWooshResponse struct {
    Status     int    `json:"status_code"`
    Status_msg string `json:"status_message"`
    Response   response
}

type response struct {
    Message        []string `json:"Messages"`
    UnknownDevices devices
}

type devices struct {
    Udevices []string `json:""`
}

func main() {
    itemInfoR := `{"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":{"Messages":["CODE_NOT_AVAILABLE"],"UnknownDevices":{"devices":["6","7","8","9","10"]}}}`
    itemInfoBytes := []byte(itemInfoR)
    var ItemInfo pushWooshResponse
    er := json.Unmarshal(itemInfoBytes, &ItemInfo)
    if er != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", er.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(ItemInfo)
    }
}
```

Output is

```
{200 OK {[CODE_NOT_AVAILABLE] {[]}}}
```

Everything is working fine except for the last part, which i am not able to unmarshall this. Can you help me out to umarshal the last part of the json.

Comment: Where is this json coming from? Do you really have no control over it? The empty key is just asking for trouble. I would recommend just making UnknownDevices an array instead of an object.

Comment: An empty string is a valid key in JSON. Make sure your marshalling method is lossless. Also, in the sample code the empty key is `devices` instead. Why?

Comment: In your sample code you have key `devices`, so you just need to add tag, try this: https://play.golang.org/p/dACrsAkadN

Comment: @RoninDev I am asssuming he is stuck with the empty key in the json. If he can change the json it is easy. Unfortunately, it looks to me like `encoding/json` can marshall empty keys, but for some reason won't unmarshal them. See https://play.golang.org/p/ut5D5bR16l EDIT: It won't marshal them either.

Comment: Some (now deleted) answers changed the type of the `Udevices` field. Instead you can implement `json.Unmarshaller` like so: https://play.golang.org/p/_TMi53hJ3o (you can also implement a custom marshaller). There may be better solutions.

Comment: @DaveC I think the custom marshaller is the correct answer. You should make an answer of that.

Comment: @captncraig unfortunately i have no control on the json, that is the json i am receiving from one of the website. And i  have to parse the json for the device id's

Comment: @GirishSatyanarayana It would probably be fragile, but if the json is consistent a simple strings.Replace may be able to preprocess it for you to add a key?

Comment: Trying the custom marshaller as mentioned by @DaveC.

Comment: Sorry folks i might be sounding dumb here, i am relatively new so thanks for your patience. when i am trying the custom marshaller as mentioned above i am finding something very funny

Comment: if the input is as pointed out by @DaveC it works but if the input is in a single line like  
`{"status_code":200,"status_message":"OK","response":{"Messages":["CODE_NOT_AVAILABLE"],"UnknownDevices":{"devices":["6","7","8","9","10"]}}}`

it does not seem to parse

http://play.golang.org/p/Zwc9kQBQN9

what am i missing here. thanks in advance

Comment: @GirishSatyanarayana That's completely different JSON from what you asked about. If you want something that parses/handles X and Y you need to write something that can parse X or Y.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be other options, but whenever you see strange JSON you can always fall back to implementing your own custom (un)marshalling by implementing [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) and/or [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler).

Perhaps something like:

```
type devices struct {
    Udevices []string
}

func (d *devices) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var x map[string][]string
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &x)
    if err == nil {
        // perhaps check that only a single
        // key exists in the map as well
        d.Udevices = x[""]
    }
    return err
}

func (d devices) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    x := map[string][]string{"": d.Udevices}
    return json.Marshal(x)
}
```

[<kbd>Playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/O8Hva-IJ51)

Comment: When i am trying something like this

http://play.golang.org/p/Zwc9kQBQN9

it does not work, however, the following works, can what am i missing
play.golang.org/p/ut5D5bR16l

Comment: You've changed the structure of the JSON so you need to adjust the unmarshalling to handle that. Your question was about unmarshalling `"": …`

Comment: oh ok got it. The reason is I am getting the json as string, so i cannot change it and need to parse it. Sure let me see how i can adjust the unmarshall thanks a lot @Dave

Comment: Also sorry i sent the wrong code. 

http://play.golang.org/p/zmGeFE8o0V

the input looks this way. sorry for the confusion

Comment: What if is only an empty array of strings the "json" response I get how to unmarshall something like this 

    [
        "some",
        "som2",
        "som3"
    ]